# Send post-request with string

Tags: ios, xcode, https, swift

I haven't been able to send a swift post-request to a server which takes a string. The server does not accept JSON data. Is there any method in a apple library? I could no find any.

Or may you even help me by telling how to write such a method?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "myUrl")
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var params = "login_act:'myUsername'&login_pwd:'myPassword'"

var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONReadingOptions.
// The following method call does not accept the params variable type, although I need to send a String
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server does not accept the json then what is the purpose of setting the header Content-Type to application/json. You have two options either send the content as json or send the post request as the form submission. I will show you both the possible ways,

The first one is simply posting the form parameters to url, which does not accept json rather accepts the url encoded form parameters.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "myUrl")
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var params = "login_act=myUsername&login_pwd=myPassword"
request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
var err: NSError?

request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")
})
```

Other approach, if your server accepts json parameters, then the approach is quite similar to the one you have done.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "myUrl")
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var params = ["login_act":"myUsername", "login_pwd":"myPassword"]

var err: NSError?
// The following method call does not accept the params variable type, although I need to send a String
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")
})
```

Comment: I need to use your first suggestion. But the params are not included into your request. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be better off using Alamofire for HTTP networking with Swift.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire